# List files at 2 directories and compare

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, duplicates

I search for duplicates in two folders. Therefor I use Windows "cmd". I want to list all files and folders which are located beneath 2 different folders. The list of files are written to two textfiles. Then I want to compare the results which are listed inside the two textfiles. 
My goal is to get a list of duplicate files or folders by comparing the textfile-lists.

So far I have some commands which are helpful (but the job is not done perfectly):

```
forfiles /p F:\firstfolder-01 /S /M *.* /C "cmd /c echo @file @fsize @fdate @ftime" >> filelist-01.txt
forfiles /p F:\secondfolder-02 /S /M *.* /C "cmd /c echo @file @fsize @fdate @ftime" >> filelist-02.txt
fc filelist-01.txt filelist-02.txt > dublicate-results.txt
```

Comment: I don't see a question. Perfection comes at a cost. For a code review see [codereview.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to get the duplicate lines:

```cmd
findstr /LIXG:"filelist-01.txt" "filelist-02.txt"
```

To write the output to another file, use [output redirection (`>`)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
findstr /LIXG:"filelist-01.txt" "filelist-02.txt" > "filelist-dups.txt"
```